# How to check if a dictionary represents a graph without using networkx package?

Tags: python, dictionary, graph-theory

Below are some sample dictionaries:

```
G = {0:[1,2], 1:[0], 2:[0]}
V = {0:[0,2], 1:[0], 2:[0]}
W = {0:[1,2], 1:[4], 2:[0]}
X = {0:[2], 1:[0], 2:[0]}
Y = [2,3,4]
```

To check if they represent a graph I tried to check that no node has itself as a neighbor, that the only things listed as neighbors are valid nodes, that if *a* has *b* as a neighbor then *b* also has *a* as a neighbor, and that all objects are of appropriate types.

```
def IsItAGraph(D):
    if type(D) is dict:
        for x in D.keys():
            if x not in D[x]:
                for y in D[x]:
                    if y in D.keys():
                        if y in D[x]:
                            if x in D[y]:
                                return True
                            else:
                                return False
                    else:
                       return False
            else:
                return False
    else:
        return False

N = [IsItAGraph(Y), IsItAGraph(G), IsItAGraph(V), IsItAGraph(W), IsItAGraph(X)]
```

When I send this in as input, as an output I get `True` for dictionaries `G` and `X` and `False` for all the others, where I should be getting `False` for everything except for `G`.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Please extend the question with the rules, what do you mean by "graph"? X is perfectly fine if you allow directed graphs, W can be fine too if you don't store empty lists, and V if you allow edges to self.

Comment: Also, as I now see your code, it returns true the first time the requirements are met, which is probably NOT what you intend.

Comment: Can you please clarify what kind of graph you are looking for? Many of the things you list are perfectly fine for graphs, e.g. "if a has b as a neighbour then b also has a as a neighbour" is not the case for directed graphs.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a function to check for each of your requirements

```
def valid_graph(g):
    for key, value in g.items():
        # Is key correct type
        if not isinstance(key, (int, str)):
            return False

        # Are all values correct type
        if not isinstance(value, list):
            return False
        
        if not all(isinstance(i, int) for i in value):
            return False

        # Do all values refer to a key in the graph
        if not all(i in g.keys() for i in value):
            return False

        # Do any keys have themself as a neighbor
        if any(i == key for i in value):
            return False

        # Do these neighbors refer back to this node
        if not all(key in g[i] for i in value):
            return False

    # All checks succeeded
    return True
```

Then for example

```
>>> valid_graph({0:[1,2], 1:[0], 2:[0]})
True
>>> valid_graph({0:[1,0], 1:[0], 2:[0]})  # 0 links to itself
False
>>> valid_graph({0:['str'], 1:[0], 2:[0]})  # invalid value type
False
>>> valid_graph({0:[2], 1:[0], 2:[0]})  # 1->0 but no 0->1
False
```

Also just to be clear, I was basically following the requirements in your question, but these are not necessarily requirements of *all* graphs. For example

- A directed graph can have a node point to a neighbor, but that neighbor does not have to point back to that node
- A graph may have cycles, including a node pointing back to itself
- A node may simply terminate and not point to any further nodes

Comment: You fixed the core issue, but did not pinpoint it, so the asker has no idea what it was.

Comment: The return for the dictionary X still remains true. Also, the keys don't need to be integers, they can be strings as well.

Comment: @VishalShahji Accordingly with your comment, you should take @CoryKramer's code, remove the `if not isinstance(key, int):` check which you don't want, and add a check that all edges are reciprocals: if we have a vertex `y` in the neighbours of `x`, then `x` should also be in the neighbours of `y`.

Comment: @VishalShahji I've updated they key to allow for either `(int, str)` and added another validation that each node neighbor also points back at that node.

Comment: @Stef That's the part I'm not able to understand how to write.

Comment: @VishalShahji This answer could be very useful for you because it fixed the main structure of your code - listing checks and returning `False` as soon as at least one test doesn't pass; finally returning `True` only if all tests have passed. Now it's your job to make sure that the tests in the code correspond to the tests you want - figure out what makes a graph a graph and what it is that you should test for to reject dictionary `X`.